# How to catch ReflectionException in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, exception, laravel

$module - is one of my classes, based on Interface and must be have public function getController. I can forget to add getController function in class, and after run i have this error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 776:
Class App\Http\Controllers\ does not exist
```

and want to catch this exception, but this code not work:

```
    try
    {
        \Route::get($module->getUrl(), $module->getController() . '@index');
    }
    catch (\ReflectionException $e)
    {

        echo 123123;
    }
```

Code example:

```
namespace App\MyModules;

MyModuleManager::bindRoute();


interface MyModuleInterface
{
    public function getUrl();

    public function getController();
}


class MyClass implements MyModuleInterface
{
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return '/url';
    }
/*
 *  for example: this method i forgdet to add
 *  and in  ModuleManager::bindRoute i want to cath exception
 *
    public function getController()
    {

    }
*/
}


class MyModuleManager
{

    static public function bindRoute()
    {
        $module = new MyClass();

        try
        {
            \Route::get($module->getUrl(), $module->getController() . '@index');
        }
        catch (\ReflectionException $e)
        {

            echo 123123;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In L5 you can handle this exception globally:

```
// Exceptions/Handler.php

use ReflectionException;

public function render($request, \Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ReflectionException) {
        // …
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: thanks. In this case, it will be triggered when any exceptions ReflectionException, but I need to catch only those that caused my code. Its really?

Comment: Sure it is :) Please add code of `ReflectionException` to your question.

Comment: it's alreay added — exception causes this command: $module->getController()

Comment: or something I do not understand

Comment: Nevermind. Just reproduced your code in my sandbox and it seems that it's impossible to handle `ReflectionException` with try-catch on `Route::get()`. So as to me global handling is the only way to perform what you want.

Comment: I added clear code in question. For run in sandbox, you should  call ModuleManager::bindRoute method